VB.NET Convert 4 bytes to an integer
Windows 11 U.S.
VB.NET, How can I convert 4 bytes in a byte array to an integer value?
I can figure out how to do two bytes using something like
IntValue = (mybyte(0) * 256) Or mybyte(1)

So if mybyte(0) = 3 and mybyte(1) = 232, or the hex equiv number 03E8, it would be int=1000.
How can I do this if I have 4 bytes? mybyte(0)..(3).
So if I had myByte(0) = 64 and the rest of the bytes (x) are 0, or the hex equiv number of 40000000, it would equal 1,073,741,824.
I tried other suggestions:
intval = Bitconverter.Toint32(mybyte, 0)

... all I get is 64.
I also tried
Dim combined As UInteger = CType(((mybyte(0) << 24) Or (mybyte(1) << 16) Or (mybyte(2) << 8) Or (mybyte(3) << 0)), UInteger)

...   all I get is 64
expecting 1,073,741,824

Maybe you could fill the array in the opposite order?

Re-added the C# tag. The OP originally added it, and so I assumed a C# solution is viable (since the OP can presumably convert it to VB.NET based on their original tags) and posted a relevant answer.

I flagged this as a duplicate, but I missed that there was already an attempt at using BitConverter and got the wrong result.  As is mentioned within the code of the answer from wohlstad (and hinted in the comment from Andrew Morton), it looks like an endianness problem.

@Itallmakescents It's often interesting how apparently simple things can need more research. For example, refreshing one's memory that the << operator doesn't widen the result.

@Itallmakescents I think it's good to have healthy skepticism about whether you should answer a question that looks basic on the surface (i.e. default to feeling like it should end up being a duplicate).

Since you also tagged C# originally (before the tags were editted), here's a solution in C# (which I assume you can convert easily to VB.NET).
Using BitConverter that you mentioned is indeed the way to go.
The following example is based on the documentation from MS: How to convert a byte array to an int:
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 64, 0, 0, 0 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first),
// reverse the byte array.
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);

Output:
int: 1073741824

Note the proper handling of Endianness to make sure the bytes are treated in the right order.
Live demo

That was the issue, I had to reverse the array to get the correct answer. Thanks to all who responded for their help. Some of the other poster's examples where helpful in better understanding the issue as well.

@KenTaylor happy to help, and thanks for accepting my answer. Just in case you are not aware, you can also upvote my answer and any other useful answer (voring and accepting is separate). See: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

When the elements of mybyte are of type Byte, doing mybyte(0)) << 24 results in a Byte, which is no good because all the bits get lost. That operator gives a result of the same type as the left operand.
You need to convert each element to the type you want to get out at the end:
Dim a = CUInt(mybyte(0)) << 24 Or CUInt(mybyte(1)) << 16 Or CUInt(mybyte(2) << 8) Or mybyte(3)

(Arithmetic bit shift has a higher precedence than bitwise operators. The final byte doesn't need to be converted to a different type.)
There was some inconsistency in the question as to whether an integer or unsigned integer was needed: change the occurrences of CUInt to CInt if the former.
If you use * and + operators, you could do
Dim b = (((mybyte(0) * 256 + mybyte(1)) * 256) + mybyte(2)) * 256 + mybyte(3)

or
Dim c = mybyte(0) * 16777216 + mybyte(1) * 65536 + mybyte(2) * 256 + mybyte(3)

which work without conversions because the multipliers 16777216,  65536, and 256 are of type Integer.
Or you could just use:
Dim n = BitConverter.ToInt32(mybyte.Reverse().ToArray(), 0)

Finally, if you're using .NET Core 2.1 or later, it's really easy:
Dim d = BinaryPrimitives.ReadInt32BigEndian(mybyte)

Docs: BinaryPrimitives Class—"Use these helpers when you need to read specific endianness."

In VB,
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim byts() As Byte = {1, 2, 3, 255}
    If BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then
        Array.Reverse(byts)
        i = BitConverter.ToInt32(byts, 0) ' i = 16909311
    Else
        i = BitConverter.ToInt32(byts, 0) ' i = -16580095
    End If

Hope it helps.
Another approach...
    Dim byts() As Byte = {1, 2, 3, 255}
    If Not BitConverter.IsLittleEndian Then
        Array.Reverse(byts)
    End If
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each b As Byte In byts
        i = i << 8
        i = i Or b
    Next

